# Node-soap client.describe()?

Tags: node.js, web-services, wsdl, node-soap

I have tried to consume a web service by using local *WSDL* file. There are two *WDSLs* that I have used.

1. *GDSQueue.wsdl*
2. *GDSQueueAbstract.wsdl*

The first one, *GDSQueue.wsdl* **imports** *GDSQueueAbstract.wsdl*. But in node-soap, when I use `client.describe()`, it shows following out put:

```
{ GdsQueueService: 
   { GdsQueueCountServicePort: {},
     GdsQueueListServicePort: {},
     GdsQueuePlaceServicePort: {},
     GdsEnterQueueServicePort: {},
     GdsExitQueueServicePort: {},
     GdsNextOnQueueServicePort: {},
     GdsClearQueueServicePort: {},
     GdsQueueAgentListServicePort: {} } }
```

Now to call a service, I should use

```
 GdsQueueService.GdsQueueCountServicePort.service(params , callback)
```

but there is not any **service method**  for calling this web service. As a result, I cant understand Why node-soap does not create **service method**.

Comment: Please add the actual WSDLs you are working with to your question, so we can better see why it's breaking.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, however you can verify the syntaxis of the call, as you should use it like

```
soap.createClient(urlOfTheWebService, function (err, client) 
{
  client.GdsQueueService.GdsQueueCountServicePort(parameter,function(err, result) 
  {
      //do something with the result or the error received
       console.log(result);
  });
}
```

);

there is no reason to add `.service` at the end of your call